# Get a list of categories of categorical variable

Tags: python, pandas, categorical-data

I have a pandas DataFrame with a column representing a categorical variable. How can I get a list of the categories? I tried `.values` on the column but that does not return the unique levels.

Comment: pd.unique(col_name)

Comment: for that you can easily use: `list(set(list(df['column'])))`

Answer (score 44, accepted):

I believe need [`Series.cat.categories`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.cat.categories.html) or [`unique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unique.html):

```
np.random.seed(1245)

a = ['No', 'Yes', 'Maybe']
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice(a, size=(10, 3)), columns=['Col1','Col2','Col3'])
df['Col1'] = pd.Categorical(df['Col1'])

print (df.dtypes)
Col1    category
Col2      object
Col3      object
dtype: object

print (df['Col1'].cat.categories)
Index(['Maybe', 'No', 'Yes'], dtype='object')

print (df['Col2'].unique())
['Yes' 'Maybe' 'No']

print (df['Col1'].unique())
[Maybe, No, Yes]
Categories (3, object): [Maybe, No, Yes]
```

Comment: You can have categories not present in the series, so `cat.categories` is safer than `unique`. Eg,`pd.Series(pd.Categorical(['a','b'], categories=['a','b','c'])).cat.categories.tolist()` gives you `['a', 'b', 'c']`.

Answer (score 10):

You can also use `value_counts()`, but it only works when you use it with a column name, with which you'll get the counts of each category as well.
Example:

```py
dataframe['Columnn name'].value_counts()
```

Alternatively, if you want the total count of categories in a variable, you can do this:

```py
dataframe['Columnn name'].value_counts().count()
```

Comment: I have a column. `df['Satisfaction']`. I want to use both of its values as hues e.g. `palette = dict(satisfied="green", neutral or dissatisfied="red")`.  Seaborn doesn't let me use `neutral or dissatisfied` because it's a string.  How do you get around issues like this if you cannot rename the column?

Answer (score 4):

Try executing the below code.

`List_Of_Categories_In_Column=list(df['Categorical Column Name'].value_counts().index)`

Answer (score 2):

This is working for me to retrieve the categories as an array

```
cat_arr = numpy.array(pd.Categorical(dataframe['col_name']).categories)
```

Answer (score 1):

df.column name.value_counts() # to see total number of values for each categories in a column

df.column name.value_counts().index # to see only the categories name

df.column name .value_counts().count() # to see how many categories in a column (only number)