# How do I check if a value is of, or promotable to, a column type in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dtype

For example, suppose I have the following DataFrame.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([['a', 1.3, 10], ['b', 2, 20]], columns=['id', 'v1', 'v2'])
df = df.astype({col: 'category' for col in df.columns[df.dtypes == object]})

print(df)
print()
print(df.dtypes)

  id   v1  v2
0  a  1.3  10
1  b  2.0  20

id    category
v1     float64
v2       int64
```

Given a value and a column identifier, I need to know whether the type of the value is compatible with the column.  (Of the same type or promotable.)

For category fields, I'd like to know if a value is in the category.  I can do something like

```
'x' in df['id'].unique()
```

but there may be a more efficient way.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have a value `x=4.3`

you can simply compare like:

`df.v1.dtype` will give the data type of the particular column you want to compare (v1 in this case)

```
type(x)==df.v1.dtype 
#output True
```

Comment: I appreciate your input.  I don't think this will handle cases where the value type is promotable to the columns type.  For instance, an int value is compatible with an int64 or a float64, but they aren't the same type so a direct comparison returns false.

Answer (score 0):

I think `'x' in df['id'].unique()` will check if the value `'x'` is in the column—which is not the same as checking if it is one of the categories.

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52405012/1609514) it looks like you check if a value is in the categorical as follows:

```
'x' in df["id"].cat.categories
```

Test:

```
ids = pd.Categorical(["a", "b"], categories=["a", "b", "c"])
assert(("c" in ids) is False)
assert(("c" in ids.categories) is True)
```

**UPDATE:**

Is this what you wanted?

```
def check_type(x, df, name):
    try:
        return x in df[name].cat.categories
    except AttributeError:
        return type(x) == df[name].dtype
```

Test:

```
assert(check_type('a', df, "ids") is True)
assert(check_type('c', df, "ids") is True)
assert(check_type(3.4, df, "ids") is False)
assert(check_type(3.4, df, "v1") is True)
assert(check_type(3.4, df, "v2") is False)
assert(check_type(3, df, "v1") is False)
assert(check_type(3, df, "v2") is True)
```

Comment: Almost.  Really close, thanks.  I've implemented your function.  3 (int) should be acceptable for a v1 (float64) or v2 (int64) value through promotion.  The function returns false as an int is neither a float64 nor an int64.  I am surprised, but a float and float64 compare as equal.

Comment: I never tried to do this kind of type-checking in Python before. I usually use `pd.to_numeric` and `pd.Series.astype` for checking or coercing numeric data types.